# Default preferences values with fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I've got an xml file with my preferences. Inside I've got several preference fragments. Each preference fragment has got its preference xml file associated. Have I to call:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
```

for each xml file? The docs says that only the first call (with false parameter) is going to write the default values. Am I missing something? How to manage multiple fragments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply to myself:

```
 // we cannot call setDefaultValues for multiple fragment based XML preference files with readAgain flag set to false, so always check KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES
        if (!PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean(PreferenceManager.KEY_HAS_SET_DEFAULT_VALUES, false)) {
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.frag1, true);
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.frag2, true);
            .......
            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.fragN, true);
        }
```